# Lark: How to make literals appear in the tree

Tags: python, parsing, literals, lark-parser

Using Python.
In my grammar, I have a line like this:

```
ipv6_comp: [ipv6_hex (":" ipv6_hex)~0..5] "::" [ipv6_hex (":" ipv6_hex)~0..5]
```

My transformer has the appropriate function

```
def ipv6_comp(self, args):
```

However, `args` looks like this:

```
<class 'list'>: ['2001', 'db8', '85a3', '8a2e', '370', '7334']
```

Because the literalls are not included. However, from this structure, its obviously impossible for me to know whether the original ip looks like either of these:

```
2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334
2001:db8:85a3:8a2e::370:7334
```

I think I could just mask the literals with their own rules like

```
colon: ":"
doublecolon: "::"
ipv6_comp: [ipv6_hex (colon ipv6_hex)~0..5] doublecolon [ipv6_hex (colon ipv6_hex)~0..5]
```

which might even be cleaner. However, the grammar I use is semi-automatically generated and this would take more manual labor.

Is there a way for my transformer function `ipv6_comp` to also include literals in the `args` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approach to solve your problem.

1. Turn `ipv6_comp` into a terminal. Then Lark will match it all in a single regexp, and return all its matched characters:

```rb
    IPV6_COMP: [HEX (":" HEX)~0..5] "::" [HEX (":" HEX)~0..5]
```

2. Provide a name for your punctuation (what you suggested, but as terminals)

   COLON: ":"
3. Use the `!` operator to include punctuation (that is: unnamed symbols) in the rule

```rb
    !ipv6_comp: [ipv6_hex (":" ipv6_hex)~0..5] "::" [ipv6_hex (":" ipv6_hex)~0..5]
```

I recommend the first solution, because it is faster to parse, and you can use a dedicated library to parse the IPv6 address into components, after the parse is done.